# Something like a Date picker for numbers

Tags: html, javascript

I have two fields in my form : one is the limit and other is value. So if I enter 30 in the limit field, then in my value field I need to open up something similar to a date picker, which shows all numbers from 1-30 and user should be allowed to pick one or multiple values.

Is there a js library that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: yet to find something that does what i need using jquery

Comment: Is a good old-fashioned `<select multiple>` out of the question? The only thing I can think of that would suit your requirements would be that or a long list of checkboxes.

Comment: My limit can exceed 100, so <select multiple> may not be pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive built it for you

http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/37/edit

Comment: I might need to end up tweaking a lot of this code to replace press me with all the numbers within my limit and appending values to my value field when the number is clicked. I was looking up if there are libraries that I can use

Comment: this is a start my frien . continue from here :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a slider? In HTML 5 you can use the below code. For browsers that do not support it you'll want to use some sort of alternative.

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="30">
```

[jQuery UI has a nice slider too](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

Comment: I need something where I can accept multiple values. So between 1-30, 1,8,10 will be acceptable values.

Comment: Yeah, that's no good then. I missed the multiple values part.